# Why do variadic functions not work with templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic

i wanted to write a function which compares several values and checks which of them is the smallest. I wanted to implement that as a variadic function template. I know there is a feature for that purpose since C++11 but for reasons i can't use that at the moment. So i tried using `<cstdarg>` library but stumbled across some problems. For some reason the offsets of the arguments are calculated wrong when i use the function as a template. If i implement the function explicitely with a fixed type i have no problems.

My code:

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>


template <typename T>
T smallestOf(const int count, const T val1, ... ) { /* I use val1 to determine the template type */
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, val1);
    T smallestVal = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        T nextVal = va_arg(args, T);
        std::cout << "nextVal: " << nextVal << std::endl;
        if(nextVal < smallestVal) smallestVal = nextVal;
    }
    va_end(args);
    return smallestVal;
}


int main() {
    std::cout << "Smallest value: " << smallestOf(3, 10, 20, 30) << std::endl;
}
```

which produces following output:

```
nextVal: 20
nextVal: 30
nextVal: 4217000
Smallest value: 20
```

which looks like the function reads past its memory as the offsets are wrong. Why is that?

Comment: Variadic functions is really a left-over from C, and have bad C++ support. For example, only the second argument `val1` will have the type `T`, the type of the other arguments is not checked and could be *anything*. Try to use [template parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) instead.

Comment: it produces wrong output whether it is a template [or not](https://ideone.com/Ncenz9)

Comment: Also, this specific function could be implemented as a [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) function that is (possibly) evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
T smallestOf(const int count, const T val1, ... )
```

when you call like this: `smallestOf(3, 10, 20, 30)` the varargs are `20 30` (because `10` is `val1`).  So you need `count - 1`.

Also **strong** recommendation: don't use varargs. Use variadic templates or `std::initializer_list`

You say you don't have access to C++11 so unfortunately don't have access to neither variadic templates or initializer lists.

Well, here is my gift for you:

```
template <class T> T min(T e1) { return e1; }
template <class T> T min(T e1, T e2) { return e1 < e2 ? e1: e2; }
template <class T> T min(T e1, T e2, T e3) { return min(e1, min(e2, e3)); }
template <class T> T min(T e1, T e2, T e3, T e4) { return min(e1, min(e2, e3, e4)); }
template <class T> T min(T e1, T e2, T e3, T e4, T e5) { return min(e1, min(e2, e3, e4, e5)); }
template <class T> T min(T e1, T e2, T e3, T e4, T e5, T e6) { return min(e1, min(e2, e3, e4, e5, e6)); }
template <class T> T min(T e1, T e2, T e3, T e4, T e5, T e6, T e7) { return min(e1, min(e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7)); }
template <class T> T min(T e1, T e2, T e3, T e4, T e5, T e6, T e7, T e8) { return min(e1, min(e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8)); }
template <class T> T min(T e1, T e2, T e3, T e4, T e5, T e6, T e7, T e8, T e9) { return min(e1, min(e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9)); }
template <class T> T min(T e1, T e2, T e3, T e4, T e5, T e6, T e7, T e8, T e9, T e10) { return min(e1, min(e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9, e10)); }
```

You might be tempted to say that is suboptimal or that you could group the calls so that there are less calls, but any decent compiler will inline and optimize all these calls for you. Both `clang` and `gcc` compile `min<int,....>` with 10 params with just branchless `mov` `cmp` and `cmov` instructions.

Comment: Oooh i see so varargs just iterates over the unnamed arguments? Yeah i propably will try to use something else.

Comment: @Yastanub you can't use C++11 at all?

Comment: Thank you very much this defenetly looks a bit overloaded(huh) but it fits for now i think.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed the comment that no c++11 is available, but since I've just written it, here's an example of a variadic solution written in c++17.

Maybe it'll be useful in future.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class...Rest>
auto smallestOf(T const& val1, Rest const&...rest) 
-> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::common_type_t<T, Rest...>, T>, T const&>
{
    auto* current = std::addressof(val1);

    if constexpr (sizeof...(Rest) > 0)
    {
        auto check = [](T const* x, T const* y)
        {
            return std::addressof(std::min(*x, *y));
        };

        ((current = check(current, std::addressof(rest))),...);
    }    
    return *current;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Smallest value: " << smallestOf(10) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Smallest value: " << smallestOf(20, 10) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Smallest value: " << smallestOf(30, 10, 20) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Smallest value: " << smallestOf(30, 10, 40, 20) << std::endl;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/600a91f1678763b2

Comment: Thanks for that i will defenately look into this when it is available